# regex whole string from a list that is not a digit

Tags: python

```
for word in wordlist:
        re.findall(r'^[^\d]', word)
        # i want to return same word IF it does not have a digit in it
        #add word to newlist and count+=1
print newlist
```

Comment: For exclusion lists, you can try using the character range to exclude, i.e. [^0-9]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily filter out what's *not* a digit by matching it to a digit which is an easy regex `^\d$`:

```
for word in words:
    if not re.match(r'^\d$', word):
        print word
```

running it on: `words = ['1', 'asds', 'sd4dsd', '234']` prints the last three elements which are indeed the elements that are *not* a single digit.

if you want to filter out *any* token that contains a digit (in the example above - to print only 'asds') modify the regex to: `.*\d.*`

Comment: Okay awesome! All were great answers actually. I think what I needed was the '.*\d.* to get the entire word filtered out if it had a number in it. I want to return each string unmodified IF it doesn't have a number :) Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension with `re.match` :

```
new_list = [word for word in wordlist if re.match(r'^[^\d]+$',word)]
```

And get the count with calling `len()` on new_list.

Example :

```
>>> wordlist = ['example1', 'ex43', 'foo', 'bar5', 'baz']  
>>> [word for word in wordlist if re.match(r'^[^\d]+$',word)]
['foo', 'baz']
```

Comment: he doesn't want to filter any number, only digits, or at least that's my understanding (sorry if I'm wrong here)

Comment: @alfasin I don't think so, due to this part *IF it does not have a digit in it*

Comment: Indeed, it is confusing... - retracted the downvote and corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to alfasin, you can iterate through the list, adding each word that does not contain a digit, add it to a list, and then return that list:

```
def no_digits(lst):
    no_digit_lst = []
    for word in lst:
        if not re.match(r'^\d$', word):
            no_digit_lst.append(word)
    return no_digit_list

print(no_digits(wordlist))
```